# Javascript: handleDragLeave and handleDragEnd not removing class effect on drag over element

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, drag

I have a drag and drop sort table row example at https://jsfiddle.net/64y1280t/. 
If you drag an item, for example, from "F" into "A", then you will still see the yellow background effect on "A". However, I have handleDragLeave and handleDragEnd handlers to remove these effects already.

HTML

```
<table id="columns">

    <tr id="a" class="column a" draggable="true">
            <td>A</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="b" class="column b" draggable="true">
            <td>B</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="c" class="column c" draggable="true">
            <td>C</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="d" class="column d" draggable="true">
            <td>D</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="e" class="column e" draggable="true">
            <td>E</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="f" class="column f" draggable="true">
            <td>F</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{
            width: 100%;
        }
tr{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  cursor: move;
}

.column.over {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sort_error{
  background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
        var dragSrcEl = null;
        var cols = [];

        function handleDragStart(e) {
            dragSrcEl = this;
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.outerHTML);
        }

        function handleDragEnd(e) {
            [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
                col.classList.remove('over');
            });
        }

        function handleDragEnter(e) {
            this.classList.add('over');
        }

        function handleDragLeave(e) {
            this.classList.remove('over');
        }

        function handleDragOver(e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
            return false;
        }

        function handleDrop(e) {
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            dragSrcEl.outerHTML = this.outerHTML;
            this.outerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
            return false;
        }

        cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
        [].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
            col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
            col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
            col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the problem.

```
function handleDrop(e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  var dragSrcElHtml = dragSrcEl.outerHTML; 
  this.classList.remove("over");
  dragSrcEl.outerHTML = this.outerHTML;
  this.outerHTML = dragSrcElHtml;
  return false;
}
```